# How to interprete when data is statistically significant with longitudinal mixed effects but not Kruskal Wallis/Welch Anova?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a repeated measures experiment with each case being measured at 3-4 timepoints. The cases are grouped into three groups.

When I analyze the measures within each timepoint e.g. timepoint 1, using either Kruskal Wallis (or Welch anova if data is heteroscedastic) across the groups, there is no significance. (I use stata and the command used is: kwallis measurement, by(group)) (for Welch anova, I use SPSS...)

However, when I center the data on timepoint 1, and then run longitudinal mixed effects, the intercept for the groups are significantly different, which suggest there is signficantly difference between the groups at timepoint 1. (stata command: mixed measurement time i.group || id: time, reml dfmethod(kroger) cov(un) no log)

The above doesn't occur for all the rest of the timepoints.

Am I right to say that longitudinal mixed effects is more likely to be "correct" as it can handle unbalanced data etc better?